# How to sum columns of an adjacency matrix in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

I have an *n x n* adjacency matrix for a directed graph. I want to search to see if any of the columns sum up to *n*. The problem is that I have to do this in *O(n)* time. Is there any way to approach this with *O(n)* time or is it not possible (no code required)?

For reference, below is the question I am trying to solve:

#### Problem:

> During the school bandmates election, each person has a few preferences for the president and the set of preferences for a person includes him/herself all the time. The "perfect" president is the one who is in the set of preferences of every person and who does not prefer anyone but him/herself. All we want to know is whether such a person exists or not.
>
> - Define a directed graph with the set of candidates as the vertices and a directed edge from vertex *a* to vertex *b* if and only if *b* is in the set of preferences of *a*.
> - There are *n* people
> - We want an algorithm which executes in *O(n)* time
> - We are given the graph described above in the form of an *n x n* adjacency matrix

I figured that if everyone votes for the "perfect president", then he/she will have *n* incoming nodes, therefore summing the column should give us *n*. If there is a better way to approach this than the way I am doing it, any hints would be appreciated to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: At a minimum, you have to read n x n values, therefore it can't be done in less than O(n^2) unless you the adjacency matrix is stored in some other format (e.g. with precomputed column sums)

Comment: FYI: "column sum is n" is not sufficient for a perfect president anyway. You also need "row sum is 1" for that person.

Comment: yup...came here to say sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me repeat the rules and give them numbers for easy reference:

1. All prefer themselves
2. All prefer the perfect president (if there is one)
3. The perfect president (if there is one) does not prefer anyone else

Let's define the adjacency matrix so that the value in row *i* and column *j* is 1 when person *i* has a preference for person *j*. All other values are 0.

The above three rules can be reformulated in terms of the adjacency matrix as follows:

1. The main diagonal of the adjacency matrix will have all 1's.
2. If the perfect president is number *i*, then column *i* will have all 1's.
3. If the perfect president is number *i*, then row *i* will have all 0's, except in column *i*.

Note that there cannot be two or more perfect presidents, as then they would have to prefer each other (rule 2), which violates rule 3.

### Algorithm: Zig-Zag Phase

The perfect president (if existing) can be found in linear time, by zig-zagging from the top-left corner of the adjacency matrix (row 0, column 0), according to the following rules:

- If the value is 1, then move down to the next row (same column)
- If the value is 0, then move right to the next column (same row)
- While staying within the boundaries of the matrix, keep repeating the first two steps.
- If you exit the matrix this phase ends. Let's call the column, where we exit the matrix, column *p*.

**Observation:** because of rule 1, this part of the algorithm will never get into the values *above* the main diagonal: the 1-values on that diagonal are like a wall that pushes us downward whenever we bump into it. You will therefore always exit the matrix via a downward move from the last row. In the most extreme case it would be a downward move at the 1 that is in the right-bottom corner (on the diagonal) of the matrix.

Here is a simple example of an adjacency matrix where arrows indicate how the algorithm dictates a path from the top-left corner to a 1 somewhere in the bottom row:

```
 1   1   0   1   0
 ↓
 1   1   0   1   0
 ↓
 0 → 1   1   1   0 
     ↓
 0   0 → 0 → 1   0
             ↓
 0   1   1   1   1
             ↓
            =p
```

Note that in this example there is a perfect president, but that is of course not a requirement: the algorithm will give you a value *p* whether or not there is a perfect president.

**Claim:** The perfect president, if there is one, has to be the person with number *p*.

### Proof

Given is the *p* returned by the above zig-zag algorithm.

First we prove by contradiction that:

#### a) the perfect president cannot be a person with a number *i* less than *p*.

So let's assume the contrary: the perfect president is person *i* and *i < p*:

Since we start the zig-zag phase in column 0 and ended up in column *p*, and since we cannot skip a column during the process, there was a moment that we were in column *i*. Since we didn't stay in that column, it must mean that column *i* has a zero in one of its rows which called us to move to the right. But rule 2 demands that if *i* is a perfect president, column *i* should only have 1-values (rule 2). Contradiction!

Secondly we prove by contradiction that:

#### b) the perfect president cannot be a person with a number *i* greater than *p*.

So let's assume the contrary: the perfect president is person *i* and *i > p*:

Since we start the zig-zag phase in row 0 and reached the last row (cf. the observation), and since we cannot skip a row during the process, there was a moment that we were in row *i*. Since we didn't stay in that row, but moved down at some point (cf. the observation: we moved out of the matrix with a downward move), it must mean that row *i* has a 1 in one of its columns which called us to move downwards. This 1 cannot be the 1 that is on the diagonal (at *[i,i]*), because we did not reach column *i*: *i* is greater than *p* and the algorithm ended in column *p*. So it must have been another 1, a second one, in row *i*.

But rule 3 demands that if *i* is a perfect president, row *i* should only have one 1-value, with all other values being zeroes. Contradiction!

These two proofs by contradiction leave us no other possible number for the perfect president, if there is one, than number *p*.

### Algorithm: Verification Phase

To actually check whether person *p* is indeed a perfect president is trivial: we can just check whether column *p* contains all 1's, and that row *p* only contains 0's, except in column *i*.

### Time Complexity

All this can be done in linear time: at most *2n-1* reads from the matrix are required in the zig-zag phase, and *2n-2* more in the final verification phase. Thus this is *O(n)*.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the proof. Can you point to other online resources, or just a name, of this algorithm?

Comment: The proof is lacking for an otherwise excellent (and correct) answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, going into more details of the proof. The added example may help visualise it. I have no reference to resources. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I am currently trying it out!